# Узнать когда загружен файл

Tags: php

Есть директория `file` в ней множество разных файлов, как удалить все файлы, которые созданы(загружены) 8 дней назад?
Больше всего интересует как получить время создания каждого файла?

Comment: почитайте примечания в описании функции [`filectime()`](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.filectime.php). Если файл был загружен и более не изменялся, этого достаточно.

Comment: Если вы проверяете аттачи(прикрепления) то правильней их учитывать через таблицу где будет время загрузки и кому они принадлежат

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Прочитать директорию *(например, с помощью [glob()](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.glob.php))*, пройти циклом по списку файлов и по условию выполнять удаление:

```
$dirname = 'file';

$fullname = __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $dirname . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
$endTime = time() - (60*60*24*8);

foreach (glob("$fullname*") as $filename) {
    if (filectime($filename) < $endTime && unlink($filename)) {
        echo 'Файл "' . basename($filename) . '" удалён!<br>';
    }
}
```